# Distinguishing between code and data pages on x86_64 MMU

Tags: x86, paging, qemu

I am trying to profile qemu in system emulation mode. The goal is to be able to identify page faults, and classify them as either data page faults or code page faults.

After studying the x86_64 architecture (this is what is being emulated), I am unable to differentiate between a code page and a data page. Does the MMU differentiate between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Page Fault occurs, use the error code that the processor pushes onto the stack to determine the cause of the fault.  This is described in Volume 3A of the [Software Developers Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html?iid=tech_vt_tech%2064-32_manuals) in Figure 6-9.  Specifically, the I/D bit indicates whether or not an instruction fetch caused the fault.

-- EDIT --

The CPU pushes the error code onto the supervisor stack after the standard exception stack frame.  See Figure 6-8 in the Programmer's Reference for a picture of the stack frame.  When control transfers to your handler, ESP points to the error code.

Comment: Would this also be the case with *emulated* cpu of qemu?

Comment: qemu should properly emulate this behavior, so yes, you can use this

Comment: Could you elaborate more on where this error is pushed? After 12 hours of reading the intel documentation, I seem stuck. Onto which stack is this error pushed?

Comment: Yes, that was it. ESP points to error code. A simple bitwise or in qemu gave me what I wanted. Thank you! Would it be wise to post my implementation details in my question, or would the qemu code be irrelevant?

Comment: This is a small niche, so I personally would not bother updating with code.  Your question was clear enough as-is.